# <script> tag in JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html, templates

I am using the template tag for my Bootstrap-navbar. Therefore I created a function that allows me to use this and everything is working fine. Except for one thing: The bootstrap nav I am using uses js for dropdowns, and I somehow cannot link the bootstrap js in my function. What can I do?

Here the code:

```js
const headerTemplate = document.createElement('template');
headerTemplate.innerHTML = `

    <link href="code/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="/index.js" type="text/javascript" defer></script>
    <script src="../code/script.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-eMNCOe7tC1doHpGoWe/6oMVemdAVTMs2xqW4mwXrXsW0L84Iytr2wi5v2QjrP/xp" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cn7l7gDp0eyniUwwAZgrzD06kc/tftFf19TOAs2zVinnD/C7E91j9yyk5//jjpt/" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <img src="/media/images/bt.svg" alt="" width="90" height="72">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link " aria-current="page" href="/de">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" href="/old">Ursprüngliches Design</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                Projekte
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/de/project/screensaver">Screensaver</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/de/project/wavy-cube">Wavy Cube</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/de/project/wave-pool">Wave Pool</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/de/project/hypno">Hypno</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/de/project/random-shapes">Random Shapes</a></li>
                <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/de/project/rolling-forests">Rolling Forests</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/de/project/pac-man">Pac-Man</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/de/project/tetris">Tetris</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/de/project/planet-defense">Planet Defense</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/de/project/tether">Tether</a></li>
                <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/de/project/snake">Snake</a></li>                
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/de/project/hunter-snake">Hunter Snake</a></li> 
                <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/de/project/maze-gen">Maze Gen</a></li>                
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/de/project/reaction-test">Reaction Test</a></li> 
                <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/de/project/mouse-snake">Mouse Snake</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/de/project/circle-trail">Circle Trail</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown navbar-nav ms-auto">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
              <img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/germany-circular.png"/>       
                DE
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/en"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/usa-circular.png"/>
              </svg>  EN</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>   
      </div>
    </nav>

  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Achtung!</h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            Wenn du zum ursprünglichen Design zurückkehrst, gibt es keinen Button o. ä., der dich direkt zu diesem Design bzw. dieser Funktionsweise zurückkehren lässt. Um dennoch hierher zurückzugelangen, musst du manuell "play.boredomtermination.tk" besuchen.
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Schließen</button>
            <a type="button" class="btn btn-primary" href="/old">Fortfahren</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>  



    


`;

class Header extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'closed' });
    shadowRoot.appendChild(headerTemplate.content);
  }
}

customElements.define('ger-nav', Header);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="de-DE">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Nav-Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ger-nav></ger-nav>

    </body>
</html>
```

Any help appreciated!

Best regards, Timon

Comment: I just got the idea of using the import js-command but I don't know how I would do that because if I import all of the js-functions the nav uses at the beginning it does not work.

Comment: Okay so i tried the import-thing and now the navbar doesn't load at all anymore? Any ideas?!